# Are train(method="glm",...) and glm(...) expected to give the same answer?

Tags: r, glm, r-caret, training-data

I'm using datsets called `trainSA` and `testSA` which, among others, have columns `chd age alcohol obesity tobacco typea ldl`.

This command (note that I'm working in R)

```
set.seed(13234)
modFit<-train(chd~ age+ alcohol+ obesity +tobacco +typea +ldl, method="glm",family="binomial", data=trainSA)
missClass(testSA$chd, predict(modFit,testSA))
```

returns `0.3116883`, while this one

```
set.seed(13234)
modFit<-glm(chd~ age+ alcohol+ obesity +tobacco +typea +ldl, family="binomial", data=trainSA)
missClass(testSA$chd, predict(modFit,testSA))
```

returns `0.2943723`.

I can run them one after the other (thus keeping every other parameter the same) with the same seed and get slightly different results.

Is this expected, or is there an extra command I need to include in one of them?

NOTE: I chose not to include details about the rest of my code in this question as they don't seem relevant, but I can do if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your outputs don't match because the `predict` function behaves differently for the two different models.  Consider this simple reproducible example.

```
library(caret)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
    y = as.factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)),
    x1 = rnorm(100),
    x2 = rnorm(100)
)
trainSA <- df[1:70,]
testSA <- df[71:100,]

modFit1<-train(y ~ x1 + x2, method="glm",family="binomial", data=trainSA)
head(predict(modFit1, testSA))
[1] 0 1 1 1 0 1
Levels: 0 1

modFit2<-glm(y ~ x1 + x2, family="binomial", data=trainSA)
head(predict(modFit2, testSA))
         71          72          73          74          75          76 
-0.06855758  0.35434220  0.09654412  0.01410099 -0.91703771  0.25432903
```

You'll need to specify change how you are using the predict functions across the two models for them to give the same results.  Here is one way to do it.

```
as.integer(predict(modFit1,testSA))-1 == as.integer(predict(modFit2, testSA, type = 'response') >= 0.5)

 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [18] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

I can't give you a full answer because you have not provided any details about your data or the `missClass` function, perhaps consider changing how you call `predict` the second go around.

```
predict(modFit,testSA, type = 'response') >= 0.5
```

The code above will give you the binary class prediction that you may be looking for, but again it depends on your data and what your function is actually doing.